# Pack horse in the forest - PC game

Tags: identify-this-game

Back in the day I played a strategygame who's name I can't remember.

I'll add a comprehensive list of details that I remember in the end of this post.

I only remember one mechanic of one mission, which is; every once in a while a small caravan of a few early medieval infantry units and a pack horse enter the map, they are ambushed in the woods and if you clear the ambushing troops with troops created in your settlement, you'll have a semi-steady income of resources.

What game is this?

Edit 1:
I played this game somewhere between 2008 and 2013, however the graphics were at a level akin of Age of Empires 2(not Remastered) I played it in German but it surely was originally English.
Also I vividly remember that I was very disappointed every time the horse "died" when it delivered the goods to my settlement, which were several singular buildings having distinct functions(troop production like stables etc., likely villager production like a town centre)

Edit 2:

- RTS, early to late medieval periods, think of AoE2(also in terms of graphics)
- Resources(Gold, Stone, Food, wood, possibly more)
- singular entities (trees, soldiers)
- narrative gameplay
- individual structures(not sure on this one)
- Memorized bit: AI spawns supply caravans(few soldiers+pack horse) which get ambushed in the forest on repeat, you can clear the enemies to receive a resource boost
- basebuilding
- unit recruitment
- German interface & voicelines, originally probably English

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a more precise timeframe? Also, in what region did you play that game? The game market in different part of the world was for a long time very diferent. It is also good to know if the game was in English or any other language.

Comment: 2008 is newer than Windows Vista…

Comment: So basically, a game that's *like* AoE2, but not?

Comment: The timeframe is way too recent for retrocomputing, have you tried reddit or somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The game that I can think of comes closes to your question, would be **Rise of Nations**.

The graphics and gameplay (ages etc.) are **very** close to AoE - You play from the Ancient age, up until the Information age.

The players (human or not) themselves can build caravans to trade between cities. Enemies can freely rob those caravans. They look like pack horses and have a guy or two following the horse. Raiding them gives you money (or, rather, "wealth").

The game also has a number of campaigns, along with some empire-building. The campaigns follow various historical events.

Rise of Nations was also released in Germany with German dubbing and UI, and came out in 2003.

IIRC, it might have been included as a freebie with one of the German gaming magazines back in the day, like GameStar or PC Games...

Answer (score -1):

Your description reminds me of [Settlers II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Settlers#Gameplay_overview) but that's too early.  However there was a [10th anniversary remake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Settlers_II_(10th_Anniversary)) in 2006 and some of the sequels had the same mix of city-building and combat - [Settlers: Rise of an Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Settlers:_Rise_of_an_Empire) (2007) and  [Settlers 7 (2010)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Settlers_7:_Paths_to_a_Kingdom), neither of which I played.

The Settlers series seems to have been in English and German from the start, at least in early iterations.  There were plenty of similar games around at the same time, but (some of) the Settlers series were among the highest-rated.

Comment: I played all games you mentioned but neither of them are the one I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not all that surprised.  I can picture a couple of others in my head but not name them, and I think I may have played one that included that exact mission in the demo version.  Can you recall what resources were modelled?

Comment: Please elaborate "resources" and bring up 1-2 examples so I can give a comprehensive answer.

Comment: In a lot of these games you have stores of gold, food, etc.  Some are more specific (meat, beer, instead of just food,  also stone, wood).  Some model people as  resources too, so you have so many serfs in a given place. For settlers 2, this guide to buildings may help https://settlers2.net/guides/guide-to-buildings - a bigger example than I can give here

Comment: I'm pretty sure the resources first mentioned hit the mark, maybe it helps to mention that the gamemechanics very much leaned on those used in the early parts of the Age of Empires series, including unit tiers (spearmen->pikemen).

Do you by any chance remember the name of the demo you mentioned previously?

Comment: @Helpme no, but there's a slim chance I've got a CD-rom with it on!. Spearmen->pikemen reminds me of nothing other than Civilization, so that's not a giveaway, having different classes of troop might give someone a clue.  Perhaps collate everything you have thought of into the question?

Comment: Please look for that CD at a convenient time, I remember this game being great fun

Comment: Spearmen -> Pikemen reminds me of Knights&Merchants, but there's definitely on caravans in that game.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid.  I found plenty I want to play (of which Caesar II, Populous The Beginning, and Settlers 4 are most on-topic for this thread - I don't think I even played Settlers 4 when I got it) but not the one you want to play